# PlayerPrefs not working on android

Tags: c#, android, save, unity-game-engine

I managed to add a score and a highscore counter to my android app. Everything went fine and worked good in Unity. I build my app and wanted to test it on my phone but the highscore counter, which is saved using PlayerPrefs wont show... There are many ways out there but nothing worked :( any ideas ?

**Here is my code**

```
 public class Score : MonoBehaviour {
 public Transform Charakter;
 public Text scoreText;
 public Text HighscoreText;

 public void Start()
 {
     HighscoreText.text = PlayerPrefs.GetString("HighScore");
     PlayerPrefs.Save();
 }

 private void Update()
 {
     scoreText.text = Charakter.position.x.ToString("0");

     int score = int.Parse(scoreText.text);
     int highscore = int.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("HighScore"));

     if (score > highscore)
     {
         PlayerPrefs.SetString("HighScore", scoreText.text);
         PlayerPrefs.Save();
     }
 }
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `PlayerPrefs.GetString("HighScore")` without a default value, so it'll return `""` if the highscore hasn't been saved yet. Since you retrieve the highscore before it's ever saved, you are probably hitting a `FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.` exception because it's returning "" to the `int.Parse()` call which is invalid input. You should switch that line to

```
int highscore = int.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("HighScore", "0"));
```

Better yet, store everything as int's and cast the int to a string for text, much safer. Track the Score and HighScore locally so that you don't have to retrieve the highscore from playerprefs every frame!

```
public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Charakter;
    public Text scoreText;
    public Text HighscoreText;

    private int Score;
    private int HighScore;

    public void Start()
    {
        HighScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore", 0);
        HighScoreText.text = HighScore.ToString();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Score = Mathf.FloorToInt(Charakter.position.x);
        scoreText.text = Score.ToString();

        if (Score > HighScore)
        {
            HighScore = Score;
            HighScoreText.text = HighScore.ToString();
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore", HighScore);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it isnt saving the Highscore. It shows only the current score. I tried to solve it but nothing :/ do you have any ideas ?

Comment: Have you verified this works in the editor and is only failing on Android? Also, when you say "It shows only the current score", what do you mean by showing? The text elements? If that's the case, the `HighScoreText.text = HighScore.ToString();` line should still result in displaying "0", which could mean you're missing a reference to HighScoreText. You could try just putting a `Debug.Log(HighScore)` at the end of the `Start()` method and see what it's loading (maybe with a default value of `-1` so you know if it fails to find it or not).

Comment: I added Debug.Log and it is showing 0. I mean the text element Highscore.text is showing the current score and not the HighScore. I'm getting this error too: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Score.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Score.cs:29)...   HighscoreText.text = HighScore.ToString();

Comment: First, I messed up and forgot to update the HighScore playerpref saving to use `SetInt()` instead of `SetString()`, so that has been updated in my answer. Second, if you're getting that null reference it means your HighScoreText field doesn't have a reference to the text element. Are you sure that you have it properly assigned in the inspector? Because you're getting that error before saving to player prefs, it won't be able to finish out the method and complete the save, which is probably why you're not seeing it saved.